# What are indices in Economics?

Tags: price-index

Really, what are indexes in Economics? And bilateral and multilateral indexes?

Take the [Malmquist Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malmquist_index#:%7E:text=The%20Malmquist%20Index%20(MI)%20is,called%20the%20Malmquist%20Productivity%20Index.): it is a bilateral index, even though it uses four numbers: $Q_1$, $Q_2$, $Q_3$ and $Q_4$?

And superlative index numbers?!

Comment: Indices (the correct plural) aggregate high dimensional data to a single number. So they are basically functions from high dimensional spaces to one dimension.

Comment: Actually: https://grammarist.com/usage/indexes-indices/. But why is the Malmquist Index a bilateral index if it maps a four-dim space to a 1-dim one?

Comment: It is bilateral because the number refers to something happening between two countries.

Comment: So the bilateral relates to the numerator and denominator then?

Comment: It is an index for a bilateral relationship. In general, that need not be related to any fraction.